# How do I redirect URLs to a common page?

Tags: typescript, angular9

I'm new in angular and working on a web app project using angular9 and I need your help.

I want the web app to have a dynamic URL for example `https://www.myMainURL.com/***` where `***` is a 3-character alphanumeric code.

So when a user types `https://www.myMainURL.com/A14` in their browser, they get redirected to the main page `https://www.myMainURL.com` and `A14` becomes the value of an input element in my web app.

I saw a [resource materials](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/), but my problem is how to implement this on a landing page in angular9 project.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need [route-parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters). Smth like `:id` in your router config and then in the component get this data via `route.paramMap`

in router config

```
{ path: ':id', component: YourMainComponent }
```

in component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap
    .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      // params.get('id'); will return the value of :id
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @v.kostenko, I'll let you know the outcome.